# HTML: Table border-left with first column hidden

Tags: html, css

I have an interesting issue adding border to table with first column of `td` invisible (`display:none`).
I simply cannot select only cells that are visible to add `border:none;` to the `first-child` using `border-left` side. Adding `hidden` to the first child of row isn't working too.

```css
    table{
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .a  {
      border:1px solid #f00;
    }
      table .td-hide{
      display:none;
    }
    table tr{
      border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    }
    table td{
      border-left:1px solid #000;
    }
    table td:not([style*="display:none"]):first-child{
      border:0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class='a'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class='td-hide'>
          </td>
          <td>name 1</td>
          <td>name 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class='td-hide'></td>
          <td>name 1</td>
          <td>name 2</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve. Where do you and do you not want to see borders?

Comment: Why do you need to worry about selecting only cells that are visible? If you can't see the cell, who cares what border it has?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-of-type(n)` ([reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp))

Like this:

```
table td:nth-of-type(2){
  border:0;
}
```

Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g54g7Le6/2/)

Comment: I have different number of columns in each case, so it should not stick to exact column number.. It should be, more, like, dynamic solution for all cases of `td` count.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS removes the bottom border on the last `<tr>`,

```
table tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

And this CSS removes the left border on the first `<td>`,

```
table td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

table .td-hide {
  display: none;
}

table tr:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

table td:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='td-hide'>
      </td>
      <td>
        name 1
      </td>
      <td>
        name 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='td-hide'>
      </td>
      <td>
        name 1
      </td>
      <td>
        name 2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='td-hide'>
      </td>
      <td>
        name 1
      </td>
      <td>
        name 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait, but if last child td will be hidden? I want `border-right`, except last VISIBLE child or `border-left` except last VISIBLE first child of `td`.. I've already tried using `:visible` selector, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @MaxWater If the element is hidden, so will the border, as proved by the invisible `<td>`'s at the start of every  `<tr>`, that have not border.